# Base64 PDF contents to PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, base64

I am interested in converting a Base64 string to a PDF. When decoded, the string looks like a PDF structure, so I figure, I need a way of writing that content to a file with the PDF extension.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you've converted your Base64 string into a `NSData`, you can use `NSData` method [`writeToFile`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIAEAHFJ), using a path in which you've used providing it a `pdf` extension.

```
NSData *data = ... // from your converted Base64 string
NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```